# SQLite3 closest timestamp

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

I have a large SQLite3 database with 30 tables the biggest one being a GPS data table with strings stored every second more or less. Other tables are in the range of 500-3000 record each. I am trying to extract from one of the tables all the records and link them to the coordinates, latitude  and longitude from the GPS table based on a matching timestamp in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss occurring in both tables. My current string is

SELECT * 
FROM gpsData, Sightings 
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',gpsData.UTC) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',Sightings.UTC);

This gives me what I need in a reasonable amount of time. The only problem is that in the GPS table I have some missing values, I guess for the GPS not having good coverage, and therefore I get many Records with NULL values. Is there a way to modify my statement so that I can search for the exact match or the closest one however back in time?

I have tried with:

SELECT * 
FROM gpsData, Sightings 
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',gpsData.UTC) >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',Sightings.UTC);

or

SELECT * 
FROM gpsData, Sightings 
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',gpsData.UTC) <= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',Sightings.UTC);

With no success. At the moment I am running the following:

SELECT *

FROM gpsData, Sightings

ORDER BY ABS(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',gpsData.UTC) - strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',Sightings.UTC)) ASC

I don't know if it is working cause the query has been running for the last one and half hours...

How can I modify my statement to get what I need in an efficient way? I have tried a few solutions proposed elsewhere but they don't seem to work for me. I am totally new to SQLite. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One issue: `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',gpsData.UTC) - strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',Sightings.UTC))`. This will try to convert the first part of the strings before the first hyphen to numbers and subtract them. So strings holding dates in the same year will always be 0.

Comment: Why are you using `stftime()` at all?